# docker-compose logs in queryable format

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I use docker-compose. The promblem: docker-compose logs returns me logs in format:

```
service_1              | {"timestamp":"2017-11-28T15:31:47.065Z","correlationId":"NO_CORRELATION_ID","tags":....
```

which is hard to query with simple scripts. Is there are a way to change the format? ideally to something like:

```
{"name": "service_1", "data": "{"timestamp":"2017-11-28T15:31:47.065Z","correlationId":"NO_CORRELATION_ID","tags":...." }
```

The goal is to filter a chain of log messages from different microservices which have the same request id.

Comment: No, `docker-compose logs` does not have an option for a different format. Can you describe what your end-goal is and perhaps we can help with a different solution?

Comment: added the goal to the question

Comment: What do you mean by "request id"? If you want to get the logs of a specific container, you can just `docker logs service_1`.

Comment: http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practice-of-node-js-in-production/ – find a unit called Assign ‘TransactionId’ to each log statement

Comment: I think doing this with Docker at all is the wrong way to go about this; it should be something that is done in your node.js application.

Comment: my node application assign the transaction id for every request, but now I need to query proper logs. What do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160126/discussion-between-tj-biddle-and-kharandziuk).